# Cant find PHP file with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, unix, directory

I have a PHP file that is located in:
`/epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php`

its permissions are `rwxrwxrwx (777)` and owners are `epcvt : users`

I want to call the `runVT.php` file by an AJAX request initiated from this file:
`/var/www/html/evtgen/evt_run.php`

I've tried to call it by this Javascript:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","/epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php" ,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

But I'm always getting a file not found response:

`The requested URL /epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php was not found on this server.`

I've also tried

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","../../../../epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php" ,true);
```

and

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php" ,true);
```

But that didn't work either.

To check if I'm missing something on the folder i went to the `/var/www/html/evtgen/` folder in the Unix and checked both:

```
vi /epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php
vi ../../../../epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php
```

And they both worked (I got the script text). What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a file in the document root (`/var/www/html/`), call it whatever you want.

Inside this file, have it call your file `/epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php`.

Example:

```
<?php

require_once '/epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/runVT.php';
```

Anything that isn't inside the document root, can't be accessed by the client-side, unless you have a PHP file linking it, (or apache rewrite, but that's another story).

Comment: Thanks, will the require_once() work if the PHP file I originally wanted to read consist of this: `exec("RunVT.ksh" . " > /dev/null &");`

Comment: Yep, it will act as if the file was in the root folder. The reason I didn't ask you to move `runVT.php` into the document root was so that dependencies such as that bash file would still be able to run. For safe measure, you might want to `exec` an absolute path, such as `exec("/epcusers/toolsamc/users/epcvt/VT/CTM/CTM80/Billing/bin/RunVT.ksh > /dev/null &");`.

Comment: One last Q, If I dont have access to the document root, i can create the new php file inside the `/var/www/html/evtgen` folder, right ?

Comment: Yes, as long as the file is a child of the document root, the client will be able to access it.